# Yii addInCondition

Tags: php, sql, yii

I've tried to get rows from table according to my conditions.
My code:

```
$conditions = array(
  'id' => array ('148028','118508')
);

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
foreach($conditions as $key => $values){
  $criteria->addInCondition($key, $values);
}
if(!is_null($limit)) $criteria->limit = $limit;

$rows = Item::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

These rows exist,but result is empty.
Binding params exist in criteria object.

Log looks like:

```
system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT * FROM `items` `t` WHERE id IN (:ycp0, :ycp1) LIMIT 2)
```

i think, that params in criteria dont bind to a query.

Is my code right?

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: show a sample `$conditions`, what does that variable look like?

Comment: $conditions = array(
  'id' => array ('148028','118508')
)

Comment: have you not turned on [parameter logging](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#enableParamLogging-detail)? that will show you the values bound to the statement, in your log. your code looks fine. how have you checked that result is empty? "binding params" are you doing something else to bind? do you have more criteria?

Comment: var_dump, print_r. No, i dont bind smth else

Comment: for me I got this message because, I had put cdbcriteria params after addInContionds(). putting params before addInConditions but after conditions fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try follow this

```
$criteria->addInCondition('id', array ('148028','118508'));
```

Comment: although there's nothing wrong with your answer, it wouldn't help, coz user6327 is doing just that in the `foreach` loop

Comment: but this works fine. i find solution, addInCondition is very sensitive to quotes. Thanks, it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
`$criteria->addInCondition($key, $values,'OR');`

where $key - field name, $values - array of parametrs